# EF Core6 how to create a json object with postgres

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am attempting to create a ef6 model with postgres that has a json column.  The table got created in the database successfully however when trying to create entries in the DB, I am met with this error

> System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated. Path: $.MarketId | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 14.
>
> System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated.

My model and constructor:

```
public class FanduelPosition
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //irrelevant columns
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public JObject BetData { get; set; }

    public FanduelPosition(int selectionId, string marketId, ...)
    {
        this.Id = marketId + "_" + selectionId.ToString() + "_" + line.ToString();

        //irrelevant columns

        dynamic betData = new JObject();
        betData.SelectionId = selectionId;
        betData.MarketId = marketId;
        this.BetData = betData;
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create a dynamic json object and insert it into postgres. Also, I have no interest in updating the json column, it will be set when the row is inserted and never updated.

Comment: Check [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#jsondocument-dom-mapping)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, I have gone through all that before I posted question. I do not want to use `JsonDocument`

Comment: Then you have to use [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)